# Prometheus remote write drop entire job

Tags: prometheus, kube-prometheus-stack

Anyone had success dropping entire job from remoteWrite ? Tried with the following config but does not seems to work.

```
remoteWrite:
    - url: >-
        https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com
      writeRelabelConfigs:
        - action: drop
          regex: >-
            serviceMonitor/ingress-nginx(.*)
          sourceLabels:
            - job
```

Thanks for the help,

Jonathan.